# Java retainAll based on Enum value

Tags: java, enums

I have a list of objects which all have a enum value called AssetType, is it possible to use the retainAll() method to sort the list so that only objects with AssetType.BANK_ACCOUNT is kept?

Thx in advance for any help.

Comment: Not straight out-of-the-box, no. `retainAll` checks for object equality, rather than any given predicate. Java 8 should introduce a more powerful collections API, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

A somewhat more intuitive Guava-based implementation would be

```
Iterables.removeIf(allAssets, new Predicate<MyObject>() {
  public boolean apply(MyObject asset) {
    return asset.getAssetType() != AssetType.BANK_ACCOUNT;
  }
});
```

...That said, honestly I would prefer the dumb, plain-Java implementation:

```
Iterator<MyObject> itr = allAssets.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  if (itr.next().getAssetType() != AssetType.BANK_ACCOUNT) {
    itr.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Louis, always like finding new stuff in Guava that I haven't used yet!  I disagree though, I would usually prefer Guava as long as you give the `Predicate` a descriptive name.  In this case I would go for `Iterables.removeIf(allAssets, not(isBankAccount));` where `not` is `Predicates.not()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you pull in `Guava`, you can make a live transform between the object and its `AssetType`, and then call `retainAll` on that:

```
Lists.transform(allAssets, assetTypeFn).retainAll(
   Collections.singleton(AssetType.BANK_ACCOUNT));


//...elsewhere...


public static final Function<MyObject, AssetType> assetTypeFn = 
  new Function<MyObject, AssetType>() {
     public AssetType apply(MyObject object) {
         return object.getAssetType();
     }
  };
```

Similarly you can use the `filter()` method if you don't want to change the original list:

```
List<MyObject> bankAccounts = Lists.newArrayList(
    Iterables.filter(allAssets, isBankAccount));


public static final Predicate<MyObject> isBankAccount = new Predicate<MyObject>() {
    public boolean apply(MyObject asset) {
        return asset.getAssetType() == AssetType.BANK_ACCOUNT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `singletonList` vs `singleton`?